# Localization in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, localization

how do I use localization in Silverlight?

since there are no local resource files in silverlight like ASP.Net. I am stuck at how would I do this?

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google returns many results:

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838238%28VS.95%29.aspx)
- [Project in Codeplex](http://silverlightlocalize.codeplex.com/)
- [Localization in Silverlight 4.0](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pchandraker/1066/)

Comment: Possibly too many :) And of course there is no concept of reputation attached to Google search ;)

Comment: My SL app is an Out Of Browser app. and the msdn article tells me that I'll have to create different xap for each culture.. :S any better solutions?

Comment: @zain: I wonder if this is just to keep the size of each XAP down per language - I am sure it would work with all resource assemblies shipped in one xap file? Have you tried it for OOB?

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight aplications are deployed as XAP files that are actually ZIP files that contains the assemblies, resources and medata of the application. If you want to localize a Silverlight application you have to add the satellite assemblies into the XAP file and then modify the metadata file to include satellite assembly files.

For example if you have MyApplication.xap that contains:

- MyApplication.dll
- AppManifest.xaml

and you want to localize it to German add

- de\MyApplication.resources.dll

and add following line to AppManifest.xaml

```
<AssemblyPart Source="de/MyApplication.resources.dll"/>
```

To get the German satellite assembly file use Visual Studio or some localization tool.